# How to fully disable auto-fill-mode in Aquamacs 3.3?

Tags: emacs

After upgrading Aquamacs to version 3.3, many modes turned on auto-fill-mode. I've followed the answers from questions such as "[How can I disable auto-fill mode in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9878623/90527)" to disable it, but without complete success. Specifically, I:

- set line-wrapping option to "Wrap" (Options→Line Wrapping→Wrap)
- turned off "Auto-Detect Line Wrap in Text Files"
- set line-wrapping options as default (Options→Line Wrapping→Adopt as Default)
- saved options
- added lines to .emacs to disable mode globally:

  ```
  (auto-fill-mode -1)
  (remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'auto-detect-wrap)
  ```
- added `(auto-fill-mode nil)` to hooks for specific modes (e.g. html-mode, nxhtml-mode, xhtml-mode).
- set text mode hook in customizations.el to disable auto-fill-mode:

  ```
  '(text-mode-hook
    '((lambda nil (auto-fill-mode nil))
      smart-spacing-mode))
  ```

Despite these changes, auto-fill-mode is enabled for some newly opened files (e.g. txt, html, svg) in Aquamacs (the system emacs also enables auto-fill-mode when entering html-mode, but not text-mode). I've grepped for `auto-fill` in the load path directories that exist but haven't found anything that appears to be enabling it:

- ~/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/
- ~/Library/Application Support/Emacs/
- ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs/
- /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp
- /Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs
- /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp

Where else might auto-fill-mode be enabled? How can I fully disable auto-fill-mode?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to  ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el:

```
(remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'auto-detect-wrap)
```

Comment: Did you read the question?